# C++ - populate derived class data members, also setting base class attribute values

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

I'm working on a program that reads some data from an existing file, stores in input into an `istream`, and filters this data into the data members of the class calling the `readDataFromFile()` method. I have this working for a base class, which I would like to extend to a derived class and use an override of the method to work for the derived class too. I am just struggling to access the data members of the base class from the derived class, as the base class contains no `set` methods.

Example:

```
//has attributes x, y
class Base {
    //declaration
    virtual void readDataFromStream(istream&);

    //definition
    //function called from inside function that passes file data into stream
    //- stream already contains data
    void Base::readDataFromStream(istream& is) {
        //insert values from stream into attributes
        is >> x;
        is >> y;
    }
}

//inherits x, y
//has new attribute z
class Derived : Base {
    //declaration
    //method inherited from Base
    virtual void readDataFromStream(istream&);

    //definition - overrides definition in Base
    //function called from inside function that passes file data into stream
    //- stream already contains data
    void Derived::readDataFromStream(istream& is) {
        //insert values from stream into attributes
        is >> x; <-- cannot access x to change value
        is >> y; <-- cannot access y to change value
        is >> z;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find a way around this at the moment, but don't see a way it can work, unless there's some kind of way to read them from the stream into individual local variables and have the object re-construct itself through it's own custom constructor, although I have never seen this before.

Any advice on where to go from here would be great, thanks.

Comment: Could you update the code to show us *exactly* where you have defined `x`, `y`, and `z`?

Comment: It would be handy to have actual code that compiles

Comment: a.k.a. we need an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You're close, but not quite there. Given that, I think I can help. I have my suspicions about why this is happening, but I need the MCVE to know for sure.

Comment: The methods that lead to this go back through a number of different classes in the program, how far would it be helpful to go back? @EdHeal

Comment: The data members are defined under the `private` section of their class' `.h` file. `x` and `y` in `Base`, `z` in `Derived`. @JasonMc92

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access to private members of the base class from a derived class.  For this you need to make these members protected instead of private:

```
class Base {
    //no visibility defined means private, not visible for derived
    int oops;  
protected:   // this is visible for derived, but not for outsiders
    int x, y; 
public:      // this is visible for everyone
    virtual void readDataFromStream(istream&);
};
```

Note also that the default visibility for the base class in class inheritance is private.  This means that users of the derived class do not have access in principle to public members of the base class (not the problem here).  You'd rather make the inheritance public unless you have serious reasons not to do so.

```
class Derived :  public Base {  // no visibility would mean private inheritance 
protected:
    int z; 
public: 
    void readDataFromStream(istream&) override;
};
```

Finally, polymorphism should not prevent you from maximizing encapsulation and maintenability:

```
void Derived::readDataFromStream(istream& is) {
    Base::readDataFromStream(is);  // do base version 
    is >> z;                       // then do more specific things
}
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/H9E8mE)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Any chance you could point me in the direction of a relevant example?

Comment: @marcuthh [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class#Private_inheritance) is a reference regarding class inheritance.

Comment: Ha, beat me to the punch! That's exactly what I suspected. Good answer.

Comment: @marcuthh I edited with a final thought that should be of interest for you bout the implementation of the overiding function.

Comment: That `Base::` access to the method was exactly what I was looking for. I'm new to polymorphism so didn't know it could be done like that! Thanks @Christophe